# Exporting geographic coordinates after Project in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, convert

I used the 'project' tool to project all layers in my map (ArcGIS v10.2) to the same coordinate system (UTM GDA 94 zone 56) to do a spatial join. However, the coordinates remain the same in the attribute table (I understand that this is normal). However, I need to export all the coordinates in UTM GDA 94 zone 56 to an excel file. I had thought I could use the tool 'Convert coordinate notation' to convert the points and then do an excel export to accomplish this, but I have not had success with the 'Convert coordinate notation' tool.

Is anyone able to assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tool "add XY coordinates" to add the fields POINT_X and POINT_Y to your layer, using the layer's projection. You may have to remove these fields if they already exist.

Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-add-xy-coordinates-to-a-file-in-arcgis/)